# Cómo realizar acción en un Fragment específico?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Haré esta consulta lo mas sencilla posible. Es la siguiente: Tengo un `MainActivity` que contiene un `ViewPager` y dos respectivos fragmentos los cual llamaré `FragmentUno` y `FragmentDos`.

Lo que intento hacer es mostrar un `Toast` en el `FragmentDos` al hacer slide del Pager pero la aplicación me lo despliega al entrar en el `MainActivity` especificamente en el FragmentUno que está como primera página. Aclaro que agregué ese `Toast` en el `onCreateView` del `FragmentDos`. Saben como funciona esto? Si mal no recuerdo los `Fragment` se crean/hacen sus operaciones al inicio. Es correcto?

Comment: Por favor agrega el codigo que te da problema para poderte entender mejor

Comment: Hola @AlexRivas gracias por tu comentario. Lo que hice fue publicar una respuesta más detallada. No sé si sea lo correcto pero lo bueno es que pude solucionar este problema.

Answer (score 0):

Estudiando un poco más encontre una solucion final. Básicamente es invocar un método en el Fragment que deseas mostrar el `Toast`.
Removemos el `Toast` del `onCreateView`:

```
public class FragmentDos extends Fragment {
    ...
    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Eliminamos el Toast de aquí
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
           // Mostrar Toast, hacer operación, etc.
        } 
        // cláusula else si lo necesitas para algo más
    }
}
```

Esto se debe a que el `ViewPager` finaliza su configuración, agrega los fragmentos de su `Adapter` y muestra el contenido.

Si quieres mostrar algún mensaje o invocar algún método ***SÓLO*** en un `Fragment` específico del `ViewPager` lo recomendable es hacer Override del método `setUserVisibleHint()`.

Comment: te recomiendo aceptar tu propia respuesta